# Date Picker In Edit Text - What's wrong in this code?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-developer-api

I tried running it, but the Edit Text View gave no respond on clicking. The Date Picker was not even opened. What is wrong in here?

Please do help me with an elaborated answer along with the full code since I'm a newbie. Thanks

**XML**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Date"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class addScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText dateFormat;
int year, month, day;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_screen);

    {
        dateFormat = findViewById(R.id.add_date);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateFormat.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(addScreen.this, (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> dateFormat.setText(SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime())), year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My guess is that EditTexts have a touch listener by default, and that is intercepting your touch events and preventing a "click" event from happening.

Comment: So what do you suggest doing?

Comment: You can not have `onClick` listener and ability to change text of `EditText` . You can use `TextView` instead of `EditText`

Comment: Thanks Ben P. I was able to solve my problem with your solution.

Comment: @mostafa3dmax Actually it turns out that we can do that and it works all fine, all we need to do is to add "  android:focusable="false"   " which will help stop the prompt of keyboard and directly listen to onClickListener on first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Ben P** said in the comment above, EditText is focusable by default.

So if you want to stop it from being shown the keyboard and just listen to the click listener you may need to stop the focus this below line do this so add it EditText declaration in your xml

```
android:focusable="false"
```

and that's it your EditText now can listen to your click listener.

**P.S.** I would recommend for you to use the material **TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText** which has a great look and follows the modern UX when it comes to create and input field and shown it to your users.

Comment: Thank you so much Ahmed. Now, it works all fine.

As I mentioned earlier that I'm new... so I'm still discovering and learning it's features.
If possible help me with a nice place from where I can learn Android Development from scratch using Java.

Comment: Hello @SuryanshKushwaha thank you, i think Google documentations and the code labs  will be a great start, Google has a training path u can use it.

https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/overview-v2

and please if my answer if correct could u please accept it as correct answer :D

Comment: I am actually taking those codelabs classes but the only thing is they do not provide stuff from the basics. At many places they just ask to copy and paste the code instead of explaining it thoroughly!

Comment: you can try this it mentioned in the above like too

https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/